# applying styles to lists in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list:

`<li> one </li>
<li> two </li>
<li> three </li>`

how can i call out a specific element in the list to apply a style to? for example: how can i call "two" can apply a style to it.

Comment: Are you interested in the second on or the one that has text of *two*?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add an ID or class to the list items in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('li:eq(1)');` is the jQuery selector for the second element (note: zero based index).  If you want to use a variable for the element number, then use something like @Soufiane `$('li').eq(num);`

in CSS you can try `li + li` and you'll get IE7+ support.

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector for the second element of an unordered list would be

```
ul>li:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: This won't get the correct element, it's not the `<ul>` that's the `:nth-child()` but the `<li>`.  To be clear, it should be `ul li:nth-child(2)`, otherwise you're looking for a `<ul>` that *itself* is the 2nd child of some other parent.

Comment: so if i have a div named "havigation", .i can access it using   $('#navigation a').find('ul').find('li').nth-child(2) in jquery

Comment: You may want to stick with using JQuery for this, the CSS :nth-child isn't supported by IE6,7 and 8 as far as I know.

Comment: @scifirocket - that's not a jquery function (functions can't have a `-` for that matter, not with dot notation), it would be  `$('#navigation a ul li:nth-child(2)`)`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('li').eq(0)
```

to get the first element